# OpenSource CMS on Symfony framework?

Tags: php, content-management-system, symfony1

I'm looking for CMS built in symfony framework. Any examples?

Comment: orangehrm latest version has built with symfony1.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe [Sympal](https://github.com/sympal/sympal) could interest you : it's writtent by jwage, who is also the author or Doctrine, the ORM used by default by symfony :

> Sympal is a Content Management System
>   built on top of the popular PHP MVC
>   framework, Symfony. 
> It's architecture
>   is simple and utilizes the native
>   Symfony plugin architecture to make
>   easy to use plug n' play CMS
>   functionality.

It's still work in progress, though, I think...

Comment: Sympal is not currently being actively developed.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a new HTML5 web content management system that is built entirely in Symfony:

[Visionary Symfony CMS (English)](http://www.virtualcreations.de/en/webproducts/visionarycms)

[Visionary Symfony CMS (German)](http://www.virtualcreations.de/webprodukte/visionarycms)

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [Diem](http://diem-project.org/).

Based on symfony 1.4, it also brings parts of Symfony 2.0 such as the Dependency Injection Container. It makes the whole thing very flexible and extensible.

Diem is already used to build dozens of complex websites, the project is very active and the community is amazing.

Comment: the project has died years ago

Answer (score 1):

Check also http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfSimpleCMSPlugin

And http://www.apostrophenow.com/

That, as is explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/d6084aba630e6099?pli=1):

> Apostrophe is an open source CMS suite
>   made up of several Symfony plugins,
>   including pkContextCMSPlugin. The
>   plugins are all under the MIT license.
>
> Apostrophe starts out as a traditional
>   CMS, dealing with pages and in-
>   context editing of slots of content on
>   pages, but also adds support for
>   'engines', entire Symfony modules
>   grafted into the CMS tree wherever the
>   admin wishes to put them. Engines
>   provide the sort of flexibility people
>   normally associate with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.steercms-project.org/ and/or http://diem-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye out for Drupal 8 (likely released in spring 2014) which will incorporate Symfony 2 components. This article describes the various components that have currently been implemented - http://www.chapterthree.com/blog/mark-ferree/drupal-developer-symfony-land

In addition whats mentioned in the article Drupal 8 has also implemented Twig as the default templating engiine.